# Отображение кириллицы в echo PHP CLI

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как научить echo корректно выдавать текст в кириллице в консольном приложении PHP CLI?

Comment: наверное можно в коде определить что это cli и использовать http://www.php.net/mb_http_output но я не уверен, т.к. моя операционка уже лет 10 как полностью поддерживает utf-8

Comment: Метод прошлого века - сделать класс-прослойку, который будет применять iconv при вызове какого-нибудь Console::echo. Конструкции, конечно, при этом разбухнут, но бонусом можно получить фильтрацию, дополнение или логирование того, что улетает в консоль.

Comment: Надо было указать в какой кодировке ваши данные/скрипт. И где смотрите: WIndows / Linux и т.д. В линуксовой консоли  кириллический текст в utf-8 выводится нормально. В виндовом cmd плохо: хоть chcp 866, хоть chcp 65001 :( Но в консоли cygwin всё хорошо :)

Answer (score 2):

Временно решено применением контрукции:

echo iconv("CP1251", "CP866", $var]);

Всем спасибо!

Comment: У вас винда? Проще chcp вызывать, наверное.

Comment: Да, скрипт отлаживаю на винде... А после отладки, наверное не нужно будет выводить сообщения в консоль, будет писаться log-файл.

Answer (score 0):

вот так можно

```
function filter($o) {
        return iconv('cp1251','utf-8',$o);
}
if(php_sapi_name() == "cli") ob_start('filter');
```